# Ajax Get +JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

In my app i m using JQuery..In tat I m using tat Ajax GEt to retrive values from cakephp controller viewforms ....But if i alert myObject..It doesnt came..

It show me the error as
    `missing ) in parenthetical {"attributes":[{"type":"Text","labels":"Untitled1"}]})`

where `{"attributes":[{"type":"Text","labels":"Untitled1"}]})` is my htm

This is my JQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./updateField",
    data: "name=" + fieldname,
    success: function(msg){
    }//success
});//ajax

//Retriving the updated value in JSON Format
var htm = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./viewforms",
    async: false
}).responseText;

var myObject = eval('(' + htm + ')');
```

But the same code works well in other system. Please suggest me....

Comment: Please show us the code that updates the "content".

Comment: Have read it several times, still the question is unclear. Could you explain more?

Comment: Is there any reason you set async to false in your ajax call?

Comment: No simply i kept it from an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your `htm` variable has an extra close parenthesis at the end, literally like so:

```
{"attributes":[{"type":"Text","labels":"Untitled1"}]})  /* extra close paren */
```

then that's your problem. Getting rid of the close parenthesis at the end forms a valid JSON string:

```
{"attributes":[{"type":"Text","labels":"Untitled1"}]}  /* no close paren */
```

Perhaps if you shed some more light on the `./viewForms` request handler (even give a code excerpt via pastebin) we could help more.

Comment: Ya now i removed the ) paranthesis and its working now.Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PHP, but can you change you output type to make it text\json, and make sure that the ./viewForms doesn't include anyother php files that generates any HTML